# Android, onClick Button

Tags: android, button, view, onclick

Although it seems like easy question I can't make it work. (There are similar questions on StackOverFlow but doesn't seem to work for me, using xml onClick attribute).

**I want to change a text when a button is clicked (basics...)**

I'm using the following code.

```
package com.example.mathieu.pangolin;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void doSomething(View v) {
        TextView myText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.worldMood);
        myText.setText("The word is happy");
    }
}
```

and the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:name="@+id/worldMood"
        android:text="Grumpy World!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button android:name="@+id/worldButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="doSomething"
        android:text="Make the World Happy" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm getting an error message, but can't figure out the solution. Kind of a NullPointerException on myText ?
What is wrong that I can't find my text by its Id?

Comment: TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.worldMood); do that in onCreate and android:name to android:id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `android:id` to specify id of an attribute not `android:name`. So change the following line,

```
android:name="@+id/worldMood"
```

to

```
android:id="@+id/worldMood"
```

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.worldMood);
        }

        public void doSomething(View v) {

            myText.setText("The word is happy");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tank you for trying to help ;) Wasn't the solution but I appreciate.